# How does jest.mock work behind the scene?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

**TD;LR** Basically as mentioned in the title, how is jest.mock implemented in order to mock ES6 modules?

As stated in the title I am wondering how [jest.mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) works behind the scene? How is it possible to change the content of one ES6 module from another one? As far as I know this is not possible with JavaScript. I am really wondering what magic is happening by Jest in order to mock modules. I am thankful for every explanation or assumption. References to other resources are also appreciated. I already found [Understanding jest mocks](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c) which is some kind of start. Unfortunately it does not really provide the level of detail I am interested in. To summarize it, I am not interested in how to use jest.mock, but rather how it is conceptually implemented.

Comment: This article [1] might give you some insight, however it doesn't dive deep into implementation details.

[1]: https://pawelgrzybek.com/mocking-functions-and-modules-with-jest/